# Static files not loading with Django. (Bootstrap not working)

Tags: python, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have read many posts about the topic and tried to follow all the suggestions (new to python here) but I am unable to get bootstrap to work in Django.

I have a project "myoffice" and an app "proposals" in it.

I have downloaded a css file and put it in following folder

django\bin\myoffice\proposals\static\bootstrap\bootstrap.min.css

I have made following changes to the settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (

os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(__file__),
        'static',
)

STATIC_URL = 'proposals/static/'
```

and included static files in my template like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
```

But it is still showing view without any formatting.

Comment: Check the Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

Comment: Check for any javascript errors by pressing F12(if using chrome browser) inside console tab

Comment: You must have ` django.contrib.staticfiles` on `INSTALLED_APPS`,  `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT` must be on your config file.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was actually a stupid error. I discovered, I have to restart the webserver after adding css file to the static directory and making changes to the settings.py

Comment: The server should restart automatically if you are in debug mode: `DEBUG=True`